# JavaScript/Ajax mouse selectable objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, mouseevent

I want to implement a JavaScript/Ajax-based client side script/module that would allow me to do the following:

1. On an html page lay out a “floor plan”, with color rectangles representing “rooms”
2. On each rectangle I need to display its number, its status (vacant or taken) and the time remaining if taken (the time counting will be done on the server, hence the Ajax)

What I need is a recommendation of a tutorial/manual that explains the graphical part of the above; that is how to draw the mouse selectable rectangles; respond to mouse events, update the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Flash and Action Script would be more suitable for that task...

If want to stick to Javascript only I suggest to generate flor plan as set of divs with specific IDs (like room ID) and execute AJAX request for status onmouseover (could be overkill) or onclick

Answer (score 0):

So you need the ability to create clickable rectangles. You may wish to use jQuery as it is a very fast and flexible dom manipulation library. Every dom element is capable of capturing a dom event (like click). The floor plan sounds like a good use case for the `position : absolute` css rule. So maybe think of it like the following:

```
/**
 * Room class represents the room.
 */
var url = "/room/rent";
function Room( id, dimensions, position, color ) {
  // keep track of the state inside the closure
  var status = 'vacant',
      id = 0,
      dom = $('#room-template').clone().attr('id', 'room-' + id ),
      remaining = null;

  function start_timer( callback ){

    var room = this;
    // the url would be the end point in your server to get the time to expire
    $.post( url, { id : id }, {
      success : function occupied( end ){
        start = new Date().getTime();
        if( start < end ){
          remaining = end - start;
          room.render();
          setTimeout( occupied, 1, end );
          return;
        }
        callback.call(room);
      },
      error : function(){
        // since we know we don't have anything working 
        // we can just try and fake it with 5 seconds
        end = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
        function occupied( end ){
          start = new Date().getTime();
          if( start < end ){
            remaining = end - start;
            room.render();
            setTimeout( occupied, 1, end );
            return;
          }
          callback.call(room);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  this.render = function(){
    dom.find('status').text(status)
       .find('remaining').text(remaining || '');
  };
  this.enter = function( event ){
    status = 'occupied';
    start_timer( this.exit );
  };
  this.exit = function(){
    remaining = null;
    status = 'vacant';
    this.render();
  };
  dom.css({'background-color': color, 
            height : dimensions.height, 
            width : dimensions.width,
            top : position.top,
            left : position.left})
     .appendTo('#floor-plan')
     .bind('click', this.enter)
     .find('.id').text('id:' + id);
}
```

var x = new Room(0, {width : 100, height : 100}, {top : 20, left : 30}, 'red');

the above JavaScript will get you started (requires jQuery, though this can easily be replaced). After that you need to get a basic html template.

```
//////////////////////HTML TEMPLATE////////////////////////////

<div id="room-template" class="room">
  <span class="id"></span>
  <span class="status"></span>
  <span class="remaining"></span>
</div>
```

great, now that is done you need the basic style for the room.

```
/////////////// CSS FILE ///////////////
.room {
  position : absolute;
}
```

So now that we have a basic skeleton for how this might work we could implement it with some data like this:

```
var floor_plan = [
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 0, left : 0, color : 'red' },
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 0, left : 100, color : 'blue' },
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 0, left : 200, color : 'gray' },
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 100, left : 0, color : 'pink' },
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 100, left : 100, color : 'orange' },
  {width : 100, height: 100, top : 100, left : 200, color : 'green' }
];

for( var i = 0, room; room = floor_plan[i]; i++) {
  var x = new Room( i, 
                   {width : room.width, height : room.width}, 
                   {top : room.top, left : room.left}, 
                   room.color);
  floor_plan[i] = x;
}
```

There is a bit of a test implementation running [at http://jsfiddle.net/Wurd5/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Wurd5/4/)